# Tomcat Server Context Setting

Tags: tomcat

I need a help in setting up context.xml in tomcat.
I have a webapp which connects to dev or test database environments according to the properties defined in context.xml in conf folder. In this case I have to change the db url everytime I want to connect to one of the db environments.

I want to avoid it. I want to setup different context.xml for each version of db so that I don't have to change context.xml eveytime. I feel we can do it by setting up multiple contexts and deploying multiple copies of the same webapp.

I tried a few things but could not get any results. Can someone please provide some inputs or guidance on this?

Comment: if you can't configure your deployment tool to do that, maybe you could try a little script to just edit context.xml (or even easier, copy the right file to the right place)

Comment: Thank you Leo. Can you please explain where can such a script be placed and how it can be called. Also what does "copy the right file to the right place" means?

Comment: keep two copies of your context file somewhere, devel and test, and copy the right one into your target tomcat

Comment: Thank you Leo. That is a really good idea. But I am dealing with a little different scenario. I have to use different context.xmls at the same time. I mean people will be using one webapp for dev and other one for test env simultaneously. I think in such a case the above method will not work. Can you provide some ideas how we can have two context.xmls ?

Comment: Deploy two webapps in the same Server. How would you use two different configurations for the same database connection?

Comment: Hi Leo, I am trying to deploy two webapps connectiong to two different databases on the same tomcat server.

Comment: If anybody out there wants to know how we can do this, here's the way. I have added <resource> tags to context.xml which are potinting to different databases. Then I added the appropriate resources to the web.xml files for the two webapps using <res-ref-name> tag. When the application loads, it maps the resource name from web.xml file and thus connects to the desired database